# Generic interface - Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

If I have the following code:

```
public interface BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{}
```

It means that it's an interface that accepts object that implement `Comparable` right?
What does `<?Super T>` means?

And the next thing, If I want to write an implementation to `BinaryTree`
How should the class deceleration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<? super T>` means *"any superclass (or superinterface) of T"* (as @GETah has quoted the docs.)

So, your class will look something like `public class MyBinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements BinaryTree<T> {...}` - you need to specify the generic parameter of MyBinaryTree to be compatible with that required by the interface.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need another `T` if you have one already bound? You can use any designation of any other additional type(s) you need (e.g. `E` or `MY_TYPE` or any other, but the convention is to use `UPPERCASE`).

Answer (score 2):

Java deﬁnes “?” to be the Unknown Type.
For a generic type G, the type instance G is the
super-type of all other type instances.

Variables of the unknown type cannot be assigned to, and are
considered as Object when reading from.

```
public void foo(G<?> g) {
  Object o = g.e; // Allowed
  g.e = new Object(); // Not allowed
}
```

For example printing an entire collection:

```
void print(Collection<?> c) {
  for(Object e: c) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
}
```

This works because Collection is the super-type of all collections.

The ancestor of the unknown type, marked `G<? extends X>`, allows to read an instance of the unknown type.
The descendant of the unknown type, marked `G<? super Y>`, allows to write to an instance of the unknown type.

Answer (score 0):

`BinaryTree` takes a type parameter, and the type parameter has to be a class which is `Comparable` with instances of itself, *or* one of its superclasses.

So say if you have a class `Frobgit`, which is declared as `implements Comparable<Frobgit>`, that would be a valid type parameter for `BinaryTree`. If it was declared as `implements Comparable<Object>`, that would also be OK.

A `BinaryTree` has to compare the objects which are stored in it, and this ensures that it is able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For the `<? super T>`, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html) says:

> The syntax ? super T denotes an unknown type that is a supertype of T